# JS and Quicktime - "QT_WriteOBJECT is not defined" error

Tags: javascript, quicktime

I keep getting the error message: QT_WriteOBJECT is not defined. My javascript is a bit messy, and I do plan to tidy it up, but everything works fine when loading the index file from my hard drive. No love playing the movies through the index file on the server though. Nothing seems to load.

I'm using the AC_QuickTime.js file provided by Apple.

Any help greatly appreciated - javascript is pretty new to me.

Index file is here:

http://www.collingwoodland.com/nicksimpson-deeks/index.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you saved the JS file to your server, probably is not referenced correctly once it moves to the server, I had that issue once.

Make sure your  tag is formed correctly or use this (which is what I do)

```
//I used them together to have access to the JavaScript functions
<script src="http://www.apple.com/library/quicktime/scripts/ac_quicktime.js" 
type="text/JavaScript"></script>

<script src="http://www.apple.com/library/quicktime/scripts/qtp_library.js" 
type="text/JavaScript"></script>
```

of post your code and maybe we can figure out what is the matter...